# Unrecognized selector for ViewController inside Container View

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

First, here's the basic setup of the Storyboard

> UIViewController > View > Container View -> UICollectionViewController

The embed segue between the container and the UICollectionViewController is "SegueA".

Now the target UICollectionViewController is subclassed with CustomCollectionVC.h.

And CustomCollectionVC has a public method:

```
- (void)updateCollection:(NSArray *)data;
```

The encompassing UIViewController needs a reference to CustomCollectionVC so:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueA"])
    {
        customCollection = (CustomCollectionVC *)segue.destinationViewController;
    }
}
```

And then, at a later point (after some data has been loaded), we call:

```
[customCollection updateCollection:data];
```

However, at this point, I get the unhelpful error of:

```
-[UICollectionViewController updateCollection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10bc73ef0
```

If this means that customCollection is not being cast properly then what am I doing wrong inside prepareForSegue?

I've seen numerous folks ask about how to reference views inside containers and they all use this method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I would suspect that you don't have your destination controller identified as a `CustomCollectionVC` in your storyboard.  Check its actual class before doing the `(CustomCollectionVC *)` cast.

Comment: Casting doesn't change the class of your controller, it only tells the controller that's what you think the class is. It looks like you haven't changed the class of your collection view controller to your custom class.

Comment: Double check all of your outlets in the Utilities panel.  Unrecognized selector is usually linked to a bad outlet.

Answer (score 0):

ok, turned out to be a very simple problem. As Philip Mills, rdelmar, and Ivan Lesko point out above, I had forgotten to set the CustomCollectionVC in the Storyboard. Damn.